# C# Checking users password & credentials SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, passwords

```
 private bool AuthenicateUser(string username, string password)
    {           
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT  cast(1 as bit) FROM Authenticate WHERE Userid = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'", username, password);
        if (GetData(sql, "UserInfo").Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if there is a shorter/better way of checking to see if the users id and password are true.

Comment: Never store passwords as plain text, hash them using salt (and a little lemon pepper)

Comment: You don't need to cast, ( select 1 from authenticate ) is enough.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am having a hard time grasping working with a database

Comment: That is not the way to [implement passwords](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/608860/understanding-and-implementing-password-hashing).

Comment: GetData also is returning a data table which has unnecessary overhead...you should also use executescalar to return a single value (in addition to all the many other issues)

Comment: In addition to what @Plutonix said (never store plain text passwords).  Your code is also super vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You **need** to parameterize your queries.  God I hope this isn't code out in the wild...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way of checking to see if the users id and password are correct.

Read [Thomas Pornin's canonical answer to How to Securely Hash Passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/39623) first.

Then, if you like, [my github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-CSharp-DeriveBytes-custom-A) has an example of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 capable code based on code @Jither wrote, as well as test vectors.

Use as many iterations as you can stand the delay for, use the SHA-512 variant, and pull no more than the hash's native number of bytes output; for SHA-512, that's 64 bytes or less of output.

Alternately, use the default native [RFC2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) function, which uses the less ideal PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1 function.